# Getting point symbols by pressing backspace, delete, up,

Tags: bash, vim, xterm

I have 2 local users on one host, both running with `/bin/bash`, I compared the `env` and `locale` settings and both are the same. But I still get these symbols "•••" on the test user while I'm pressing `backspace`, `delete` or `arrow keys` in `vim` if I'm on top or bottom. `.bashrc` also looks like the same of the productive user and I'm also using the same SSH connection settings via rebex.

Anything else what I forgot to check?

Comment: Those characters are added to the document? What characters are they exactly? (Position over them and hit `ga`.) If that's not what you meant can you clarify what you did mean? Do they behave "normally" at the shell prompt? Did you check the user's `.vimrc` files? Does `vim -u NONE -U NONE` behave differently for the test user?

Comment: Check your terminal settings.

Comment: @Etan Reisner - The symbols aren't saved to the file and are also shown in bash, if I save, close and reopen the file, all symbols disappeared.

Comment: @e0k - I checked the terminal settings, the same settings worked correctly on the same machine on another user.

Comment: This only happens in vim? Only at the top or bottom of the document? What are the characters *exactly*? Did you run that vim command to rule out vim settings?

Comment: No, not only in vim. But got more confused, I tried the same rebex terminal emulator on another PC running same OS (Win 8.1) and it works, the rebex config is saved in mySQL so it's 100% the same as on the other PC. So it's clear that this is not a term/bash/vim problem. I will try to clear cache etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by clearing the cache, there was a kind of bug in `RemoteDesktopManager`, because normally the session should be refreshed every minute.

Like I told in the comments, I got on the same PC, with same settings, on one of two users on the same host, some kind of symbols. Same settings on another PC still works, so there wasn't any problem with `xterm`, `bash` or `vim`.